# Ansbile: File not loading with include_vars module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using `include_vars` module with `files_matching` option to load a yaml file. I don't see any error while running the playbook, but it's not loading the yaml file

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    work_folder: /home/ubuntu/vars
  tasks:
    - name: Load yaml file
      include_vars:
        dir: "/home/ubuntu/vars"
        files_matching: "^(.*)-hive-proxy_values.yaml"
        name: hive_proxy_values

    - debug:
        var: "{{ hive_proxy_values}}"
```

Output

```
TASK [Load yaml file] *************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/ubuntu/hive.yaml:7
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "hive_proxy_values": {}
    },
    "ansible_included_var_files": [],
    "changed": false
}

ok: [localhost] => {
    "<class 'dict'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: "
}
```

File exists in `/home/ubuntu/vars` folder

```
ls -l /home/ubuntu/vars
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 145 Aug 15 05:20 mtn-wbel-AAA-OAM-12x-hive-proxy_values.yaml
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this failure unless I change the permissions on `/home/ubuntu/vars` so that the user executing the playbook does not have access to read that directory.

Comment: Don't expand it, i.e. don't put it into the braces `"{{ }}"` if you want to display a variable `var: hive_proxy_values`. You ask *debug* to show you the value of the variable whose name is stored in *hive_proxy_values*. The value of *hive_proxy_values* is not the name of another variable. This is the reason for the error: `"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: "`

Comment: @flowerysong were you able to see value in `"ansible_included_var_files": [],` ?

Comment: Yes.  ```"ansible_included_var_files": [
        "/home/ubuntu/vars/mtn-wbel-AAA-OAM-12x-hive-proxy_values.yaml"
    ],```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the braces `"{{ }}"`

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: hive_proxy_values
```

---

**Examples**

Given the tree and the content

```
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yaml
└── vars
    └── 01-test.yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

```yaml
shell> cat vars/01-test.yaml 
test_var: value from vars/01-test.yaml
```

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yaml 
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:

    - block:
        - include_vars:
            dir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars"
            files_matching: "^(.*)-test.yaml"
            name: hive_proxy_values
        - debug:
            var: hive_proxy_values
      tags: test

    - block:
        - include_vars:
            dir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars"
            files_matching: "^(.*)-missing.yaml"
            name: hive_proxy_values
        - debug:
            var: hive_proxy_values
      tags: missing
```

- The module *include_vars* reads *vars/01-test.yaml*. The dictionary *hive_proxy_values* keeps the content of *vars/01-test.yaml*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yaml -t test

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hive_proxy_values:
    test_var: value from vars/01-test.yaml

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- When *files_matching* doesn't much any file the module *include_vars* reads nothing and the dictionary *hive_proxy_values* is empty

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yaml -t missing

PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************

TASK [include_vars] *********************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  hive_proxy_values: {}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The registered variable only shows what we already know. Both the list of the files and the dictionary *hive_proxy_values* are empty

```yaml
    - block:
        - include_vars:
            dir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/vars"
            files_matching: "^(.*)-missing.yaml"
            name: hive_proxy_values
          register: result
        - debug:
            var: result
        - debug:
            var: hive_proxy_values
      tags: missing
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result:
    ansible_facts:
      hive_proxy_values: {}
    ansible_included_var_files: []
    changed: false
    failed: false
```

Comment: I tired  `hive_proxy_values` without {{}}. it didn't work. I think the issue in `Load yaml file` task as `"ansible_included_var_files": [],` is empty

Comment: The same task also shows `hive_proxy_values: {}` is empty. It's difficult to believe the debug might fail.